# noob: add 2 strings from json to custom listadapter

Tags: android

Im looking to run a query on my external database, i got all the coding done up to this point. Although the coding works, I need it to put the "name" and the "cphone" in an array of some sort so i can add it to the custom list adapter as a double row.

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

*name*

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

*cphone*

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

to this

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

*name        cphone*

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
Log.d("RESULT", result);

        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = json_data.getString("username");
                String cphone = json_data.getString("password");
                items.add(name);
                items.add(cphone);
                Log.d(name, "Sever Output");
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getdata.this, R.layout.stashrow, items);
            ListView sList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liststash);
            sList.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("errorLog", "Error makingView: " + e.toString());
        }
```

the problem stands in the item.add(), i can only put one value in at a time so it makes it 2 different lines. If I try adding another textview to the stashrow, it errors out. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic ArrayAdapter isn't configured to do very much.  If you're content with the simple formatting of 
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

name cphone

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Then you might as well just concatenate the strings together:

```
String name = json_data.getString("username");
String cphone = json_data.getString("password");
String user = name + " " + cphone;
items.add(user);
```

For anything more complicated then that, you're better off defining your own data object (like a `User` for instance, with a `getName()` and `getCPhone()`) and then subclassing ArrayAdapter to translate the objects in the array into the well formatted ListView you really want - like so:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
// Constructor, etc
...
@Override
public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  View view = convertView;
  if (view == null) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stashrow, null);
  }
  User user = items.get(position)
  TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stash_row_name);
  TextView chpone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stash_row_cphone);
  name.setText(user.getName());
  cphone.setText(user.getCPhone());
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I apreciate it, but the custom list adapter needs 2 items to put in different textviews for the stashrow layout. The layout actually has an imageView, textView, textView, but I can get the image part once i figure this out.

Comment: @LewisMcClair Like I said, for anything more drastic than that, you'll have to extend the ArrayAdapter - updating w/ an example

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't even see that paragraph, but yes I do understand what your saying now. I appreciate it.